# Объединение элементов массива python

Tags: python, массивы

Есть массив такого вида, с множеством таких объектов

```
["Name", "1", "234", "11", "name"...... ]
```

нужно чтобы каждые 5 элементов были одной строкой, может кто подсказать как это сделать?
Была попытка объедения таким способом:

```
my_list=['name', '1', '2, '3', 'name'...] 
my_list=[''.join(my_list)]
```

Всё склеивается в одну строку без пробелов, и склеивает весь масив

Comment: "чтобы каждые 5 элементов были одной строкой"  пример приведите. Ваша попытка в виде кода

Comment: my_list=['name', '1', '2', '3', 'name'] 
my_list=[''.join(my_list)]

Comment: Прямо в вопрос ваш код добавляйте. Ну, всё правильно. Осталось как-то проитерироваться по списку так, чтобы брать по 5 элементов из него. И есть такая штука как *срез*, например.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
elements = ["Name", "1", "234", "11", "name"] * 20
# Это типа ваш список но в 20 раз длинее ______^^^ 
step = 5

print(
    *(', '.join(elements[i: i + step]) for i in range(0, len(elements), step)), sep='\n'
)
# Name, 1, 234, 11, name
# Name, 1, 234, 11, name
# Name, 1, 234, 11, name
# Name, 1, 234, 11, name
# Name, 1, 234, 11, name
...
# Name, 1, 234, 11, name
# Name, 1, 234, 11, name
```